# why dig command in cygwin allways return "Segmentation fault"?

Tags: windows, segmentation-fault, cygwin, dig

I was installed cygwin on Windows 7 and when I tried to use *dig* command, cygwin always return "Segmentation fault ('core' generated). I don't know why.

I've installed cygwin with bind-packets too, but it seems don't work.

Is there anything else to do to make this work? Anything more to install?

Thanks.

Comment: It should not segfault. Try reinstalling the `bind-utils` packages

Comment: I tried a couple of times, but it seems that didn't install them ...

Comment: dig is part of bind-utils. Do you know how to re-install a package from setup ?

Comment: Yes, I know it. And when I try to re-install Cygwin I have selected bind-utils library in widard setup, but it seems that not install.. i don't know why...

Comment: broken mirror ? Installing from local repository ?

Answer (score 1):

Segfault could be caused by manual installations and/or corrupted setup.ini files; try removing the whole cygwin package and running the setup again.
I used to run dig on Windows 7 and it worked(*).

(*) note that the current version (9.11.0-2.P3) does not work for me, i.e. returns no output when querying a Windows-based DNS server.
Posted a bug on cygwin mail list, hopefully it will be fixed.